# Javascript for class won't work properly- j.query, animation, interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, setinterval

I am trying to do script that animate background color for paragraph. I have got something like this:

```
var time = 500;
var liczbaid = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
myVar = setInterval(function() { kolorgora() }, 3000);

function kolorgora(){
    for (i = 0; i <= liczbaid.length; i++){
        var p = $("#" + i);
        p.animate({backgroundColor: "#aa0000"}, 1000+i*time);
        p.animate({backgroundColor: "#ffffff"}, 2000+i*time);
    }
};

function kolordol(){
    for (i = 0; i <= liczbaid.length; i++){
        var p = $("#" + (liczbaid.length-i));
        p.animate({backgroundColor: "#aa0000"}, 1000+i*time);
        p.animate({backgroundColor: "#ffffff"}, 2000+i*time);
    }
};
```

or something like this:

```
var time = 500;
var liczbaid = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var zmienna = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() { kolorif() }, 3000);

function kolorif() {
    for (i = 0; i <= liczbaid.length; i++) {
        if (zmienna == 0) {
            var p = $("#" + i);
            p.animate({backgroundColor: "#aa0000"}, 1000+i*time);
            p.animate({backgroundColor: "#ffffff"}, 2000+i*time);
        } else if (zmienna == 1) {
            var p = $("#" + (liczbaid.length-i));
            p.animate({backgroundColor: "#aa0000"}, 1000+i*time);
            p.animate({backgroundColor: "#ffffff"}, 2000+i*time);
        } else if (zmienna == 2) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is it need to go all way down from the start and when I click the button it reverse and go all the way up. I try everything from switch to change variable by the button but nothing works. Any clue?

https://jsfiddle.net/gceoae3b/

Comment: I'd suggest providing a CodePen or a JSFiddle so people can easily understand what you're trying to achieve and what is going wrong.

Comment: jsfiddle already in the post. Reverse work  but i need to have possibility to change the direction with buttons.